# Vertical spacing between equations and text

Tags: spacing, equations, nomenclature

I'm running into an issue where if I add `\nomenclature{$a$}{A}%` after an equation it adds extra space.  I have many equations and half of them require the `\nomenclature` command, however, those that don't have awkward spacing.  I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7.

I've tried using `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` and `\vspace{-\parskip}` to no avail.

Using the example below you can skip between pages 2 & 3 and you can easily tell that the the bottom equation is being `pushed' downwards.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\printnomenclature
\cleardoublepage
\begin{equation}
a=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
b=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\nomenclature{$b$}{Anything}%
\vspace{-    \parskip}
\begin{equation}
c=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\cleardoublepage
\begin{equation}
a=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
b=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
c=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you put `\nomenclature` *inside* the equation environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the `\nomenclature` command *inside* the equation environment.

Recall also that consecutive display environments are not recommended and that `amsmath` provides many environments for displays. Here's with `align`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature

\cleardoublepage

Some text
\begin{equation}
a=A
\nomenclature{$a$}{Anything}
\end{equation}
Some other text
\begin{align}
a&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\\
b&=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\nomenclature{$b$}{Anything}
\\
c&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, +1. For me it was between theorem environments, so it seems not to be specific to math display environments. (Worst case was: *after* `\end{equation}` and *before* `\end{theorem}`. Really big space before the next `\begin{theorem}`.)